# Closure Compiler: JSC_POSSIBLE_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property ajax never defined on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I am getting the following warnings when trying to compile via the UI, some JavaScript code and have tried suppressing them several ways but cannot get this to compile; what am I doing wrong? TIA, DaveGee

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @language_out ES5
// @output_file_name default.js
// --jscomp_off=missingProperties
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

if (test_connection == true) {
  jquery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url + index,
    async: false,
    headers: http_headers,
    error: function(response) {
      throw new Error("Error connecting to Search Engine: " + response.statusText);
    }
});

error: function(response) {
  throw new Error("Error querying Search Engine: " + response.statusText);
  console.log(errorThrown);
```

> JSC_POSSIBLE_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property ajax never defined on jquery at line 26 character 10 jquery.ajax({
>
> JSC_UNREACHABLE_CODE: unreachable code at line 82 character 4 console.log(errorThrown);

Answer (score 1):

> JSC_POSSIBLE_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property ajax never defined on jquery at line 26 character 10 jquery.ajax({

This is because the variable name should be `jQuery` or `$`, not `jquery` (assuming you've not aliased jQuery, but I'm assuming not as you wouldn't have the error). Remember that Javascript is case-sensitive.

> JSC_UNREACHABLE_CODE: unreachable code at line 82 character 4 console.log(errorThrown);

This is because you've placed code *after* a `throw` call, where execution will exit the function. Move the `console.log()` before the `throw`.

Also note that you should remove `async: false` as it's very bad practice. You should use the callback pattern instead; as you are for the `error` handler.

Comment: Tried both jQuery and $, same issue..JSC_POSSIBLE_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property ajax never defined on jQuery at line 25 character 10
   jQuery.ajax({         JSC_POSSIBLE_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property ajax never defined on $ at line 25 character 5
   $.ajax({

Comment: In which case are you sure that you've added jQuery.js to the page properly? Also check you're not using the 'slim' version of jQuery as it does not have any AJAX functionality, amongst other things.

Comment: Moving the console.log did the trick on those warnings, Thanks Much. as for the ajax error, not aliased jQuery or $, is this something i need to do in order to get closure to compile cleanly? I'm a newbie to this compiler so bear with me please..

Comment: I have jQuery defined in my HTML page as Javascript includes have global scope, so this js file will still have access to jQuery as well. It is defined as follows: <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> This code all runs fine natively, just trying to Closure it..